# SWT Button image limit

Tags: java, image, button, swt, border

When an image is set on a SWT `Button` and the image is bigger (in this case the width), the limits of the button are not honored, and the image from one button can "touch" the image from another.

[image]

Strangely, if `SWT.LEFT` or `SWT.RIGHT` is used, the problem does no occur on the respective side. Tried with `SWT.CENTER`, without success.

Is there any "workaround" to bypass this problem? Or is just something that any SWT user must get used to?

Composite Code:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
gridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
gridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
gridLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
setLayout(gridLayout);
setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

Button Code:

```
Button button=new Button(this, SWT.PUSH | SWT.WRAP);
GridData gridData=new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
gridData.widthHint=size.width;
gridData.heightHint=size.height;
button.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

I also have a listener associated with the Composite Layout, to adjust the Number of Columns, but i assume that's irrelevant.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a `Button`? Can't you use a `Label` and add a `Listener` for mouse clicks? Which `Layout` are you using for the `Composite` hosting the `Button`s?

Comment: BTW: Do you restrict the `Button` width or do you use a `Layout` for the arrangement?

Comment: I edited the question with the code used. The Label does not suffer from this problem? I have a very complex set of GROUPS with several Composites with buttons in them...

Comment: So you restrict the size of the buttons. Is this necessary? Isn't the `GridLayout` sufficient? What are your requirements? As for the `Label`: Just try it.

Comment: The size IS necessary, but the Label is JUST PERFECT! Button is really tricky (not to say buggy... ) when handling images. Please put your suggestion as an answer so i can accept it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Button` for this task doesn't seem to be the best choice (because of the borders).

You might be better off using a `Label` to host the `Image`. Your code will only change very little, since you only need to replace all occurrences of `Button` with `Label`.

Comment: Just a note to say that every widget has its limitations... the Label does not "center" the image, as opposed to the button.